# Relating tables based on a range of values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, relationship-class, address

I have a polygon shapefile of parcels with 2 fields that give a low and high address range. I would like to relate this to a point shapefile that has a specific address field for each point. The Addresses are homogenized strings in both files, I just need a way to relate each parcel address range to the exact addresses so I can select them and see where they are.

That is when I want to access the related table for Parcel 10,  with address range 1428-1430 1st avenue, I would like to have selected ALL points in the related table namely:

- 1428 1st ave
- 1429 1st ave
- 1430 1st ave

Is there any way to generate slightly more complex relationships like this on Arcmap?

Answer (score 1):

I understand what the homogonized string is in the points, but am not sure what the parcel strings look like if they are homogonized strings in two fields.  You have only written a single string as the range and not two separate strings, so that makes no sense to me.

The addresses need to be standardized, since 1st avenue and 1st ave won't join without some further processing to a standard format, either using geocoding tools or python scripting/replace calculations.

If the street names were identical and only the numbers were the issue a python script using cursors and dictionaries would not be that hard to write to split the strings, match the street names, and evaluate the ranges to write a common single numeric field to both feature classes with values representing each range.  But before providing an example script I would want to know exactly how the strings are formatted and how much standardization needs to take place to get the street names to match exactly.  Python cold also employ a SoundEx algorithm, but more false matches would occur the farther away you get from exact matches.

Since you are dealing with both sources being spatial data, a Spatial Join with buffering could play a role in reducing the possible range candidates and help with the street and range matching process.  A screen shot of the point and parcel distribution would be required to evaluate whether or not that is another possible approach.